# React - How to keep track of the users current position on page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a single page website that scrolls into different sections with each nav item click. Currently if I scroll away from one of the sections, the nav bar is unaware and wont allow scrolling to the previously clicked section.

I would like to be able to track where the user is on the page and have the nav bar be responsive accordingly.

All the app components are rendered here:

```
function App() {
  const homeRef = useRef();
  const aboutRef = useRef();
  const portRef = useRef();
  const contactRef = useRef();
  const [selection, setSelection] = useState("home");
  const handleSelect = (select) => {
    setSelection(select);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    if (selection === "home") {
      homeRef.current.scrollIntoView({
        behavior: "smooth",
        block: "start",
      });
    }
    if (selection === "about") {
      aboutRef.current.scrollIntoView({
        behavior: "smooth",
        block: "start",
      });
    }
    if (selection === "portfolio") {
      portRef.current.scrollIntoView({
        behavior: "smooth",
        block: "start",
      });
    }
    if (selection === "contact") {
      contactRef.current.scrollIntoView({
        behavior: "smooth",
        block: "start",
      });
    }
  },[selection]);
  return (
    <div className="allShared">
      <Navigation className="nav" onNavSelection={handleSelect}></Navigation>
      <div ref={homeRef}>
        <Home></Home>
        </div>
        <div ref={aboutRef}>
        <About></About>
        </div>
        <div ref={portRef}>
        <Portfolio></Portfolio>
        </div>
        <div ref={contactRef}>
        <Contact></Contact>
        </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Child component passes which nav item is clicked to parent.

```
const Navigation = (props) => {
  const sendData = (key) =>{
    props.onNavSelection(key)
  }
  return (
    <Navbar
      className="nav "
      collapseOnSelect
      expand="lg"
      fixed="top"
      bg="dark"
      variant="dark"
      style={{
        opacity: "0.9",
      }}
    >
      <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav" />
      <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav">
        <Nav className="mr-auto mr-5" onSelect={(selectedKey)=>sendData(selectedKey)}>
          <Nav.Link eventKey="home">Home</Nav.Link>
          <Nav.Link eventKey="about">About</Nav.Link>
          <Nav.Link eventKey="portfolio">Portfolio</Nav.Link>
          <Nav.Link eventKey="contact">Contact</Nav.Link>
          <Nav.Link target="_blank" href="">CV</Nav.Link>
        </Nav>
      </Navbar.Collapse>
    </Navbar>
  );
};

export default Navigation;
```

Any pointers and tips are appreciated.

Comment: That might help you https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scrollable-anchor

Answer (score 1):

you can create your own custom hook to track the page scroll coordinate

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export default () => {
  const [scrollPosition, setScrollPosition] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleScroll = () => setScrollPosition(window.scrollY);
    document.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    return () => 
      document.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
  }, []);
  return scrollPosition;
}
```

then use it in the component

```
import React from 'react';
import useBodyScrollPosition from './use-body-scroll-position';

export default () => {
  const scrollPosition = useBodyScrollPosition();
  const wrapperStyles = {
    height: '5000px',
  };
  const displayStyles = {
    position: 'fixed',
    width: '100%',
    top: '50%',
    transform: 'translateY(-50%)',
    fontSize: '20px',
    textAlign: 'center',
  }
  return (
    <div style={wrapperStyles}>
      <div style={displayStyles}>
        {scrollPosition !== null ? scrollPosition : 0}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

I was searching on custom hooks and I remembered this thing.
check it from the original author:
https://dev.to/wellpaidgeek/how-to-write-custom-hooks-in-react-1ana